# "Reverse incremental" backup for Windows?

Tags: windows, backup, incremental-backup, rsnapshot

I am looking for a way to make a "reverse incremental" backup under Windows.
What I mean by reverse incremental is:

source folder (S):

- files a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

target folder:

- newest backup (let's call it 0 (as zero)) has all files a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

Now say I change files e,f,g,h in the source folder and run a backup after, it should do the following:

- make a new folder that has a complete copy
- in the former newest backup, it should ONLY retain the files that are different  from the last backup to now.

(In practice, it should rotate all old copies 1,2,3,n down by one to 2,3,4,n+1, then make a new folder called 1. All the files which were changed in S should be copied from 0 to 1, and then from S to 0.)

Basically it should kinda reproduce the behaviour of rsnapshot for the current copy, without using any symlink/softlink/hardlink business to make the "old" copies directly accessible (because all that stuff on Windows is so-so, plus network drives etc.)

Is there anything good that does this?

In this case I would prefer GUI but commandline will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used rdiff-backup (http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/), but **I don't recommend it** for the reasons I'm explaining below. rdiff-backup is a command line python script and can be used on Windows either natively or via cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/).

I stopped using it because of some reliability problems that caused the software to stop in the middle of the backup - sometime corrupting the backup itself. I suspect these could be specific to my configuration (~1T of data to backup, TortoiseSVN monitoring files, Antivirus), but I wouldn't recommend a backup solution that cannot cope with these conditions.

Anyway maybe you want to run some tests and - if your python skills are better than mine - try to fix it.